# SwiftUI picker .onChanged only firing on 2+ selection changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a picker that will change an attribute of an object that is bound to the view. When the picker is changed I want to update the bound object so the change is apparent in the previous view. The picker updates the label on each change but the .onChanged modifier does't fire after the first change. If changed 2 or more times the .onChanged body fires.

```
let categories: [String] = ["None", "Produce", "Dairy/Eggs", "Meat", "Breads", "Canned Goods", "Baking", "Frozen", "Bulk", "Snack Foods", "Spices/Seasonings", "Pasta/Rice", "Drinks", "Liquor", "Condiments"]

    //Name of recipe received from previous view
    @Binding var ingredient: Ingredient
   
    
    //ingredient variable that can be updated
    @State var category: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(ingredient.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                Menu {
                    Picker("picker", selection: $category) {
                        ForEach(categories, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                    .onChange(of: category, perform: { newValue in
                        print("PICKER CHANGED")
                        ingredient.category = self.category

                    })
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
                    
                } label: {
                    Text(category)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(5)
                        .labelsHidden()
                        .clipped()
                        .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous))
                }
         }
    .onAppear(perform: {self.category = ingredient.category})
}
```

Ingredient class:

```
class Ingredient: Identifiable, Hashable{
    static func == (lhs: Ingredient, rhs: Ingredient) -> Bool {
        if (lhs.id == rhs.id) {return true}
        else {return false}
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    public var id = UUID()
    public var name: String = ""
    public var inStock: Bool = false
    public var category: String = ""
    public var keepInStock: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Just use `$ingredient.category` as the `Picker` `selection`

Comment: @loremipsum That works but the label is not updating. Also, suppose I want to store the change in a DB, is there any alternative to .onChanged, I was thinking .onDisappear.

Comment: Just get. rid of the `@State  var category` it isn't needed. By connecting it all through `$ingredient.category` when you persist to a database it will all get updated. It is best to have a `Save` Button. `onAppear`, `onChange`, and `onDismiss` seems to be unreliable. You can try but I would not count on them

Comment: I made those changes and it works well. But the label does not update. I'm using a hacky label thing on top of the picker so that may be why there is an issue. It doesn't update when the bound ingredient object is changed.

Comment: @loremipsum here is what the label is doing. It doesn't recognize that the ingredient binding has changed. https://imgur.com/a/niUvg8Z

Comment: Because ingredient is a `class` change it to a `struct` OR make it an `ObservableObject` wrap the variables in `@Published` and change `@Binding var ingredient: Ingredient` to `@ObservedObject var ingredient: Ingredient`

Comment: @loremipsum That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help. This change also fixed a few other issues I was having. Very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because SwiftUI does not know about the changes.

`Ingredient` is a `class` change it to a `struct`

OR

make it an `ObservableObject` wrap the variables in `@Published` and change

```
@Binding var ingredient: Ingredient
```

to

```
@ObservedObject var ingredient: Ingredient
```

`class` is reference type and `struct` is value type.

`@State`, `@Binding`, `@Published` see changes for value type.

`@ObservedObject`, `@StateObject`, and `@EnvironmentObject` are for reference. Accompanied by `ObservableObject` and `@Published`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a `tag` modifier on the `Text` property inside the `ForEach` for the picker?

```swift
Picker("picker", selection: $category) {
    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) {
        Text($0).tag($0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it still results in the same behavior. I am getting the right value but it is delayed by one interaction. .onChange doesn't recognize the first changed make with the picker, but the second and all subsequent changes are recognized. Its as if after detecting the first change the program breaks and then finishes firing after the next change is made.